# Webpack ag-grid-enterprise import

Tags: webpack, import, ecmascript-6, ag-grid

I try to use ag-grid-enterprise in my app (webpack build).
I import thats way:

```
import * as agGrid from 'ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise/main'
```

The agGrid functionality is working, but the enterprise methods are not available.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the call to `setLicenseKey` as described here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-license/

It's not clear how your question is related to webpack, but I'm assuming the code you supplied is in an [entrypoint as specified in your webpack config](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

You'll need to put the following near the top of that entrypoint module:

```
// enable ag-Grid Enterprise features
import { LicenseManager } from "ag-grid-enterprise/main";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("YOUR_LICENSE_KEY");
```